# Problems using Smart Location Library

Tags: android, location

I am trying to use the [Smart Location Library](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib) to obtain periodic location updates. But when start the process it fires the listener once then there is no further updates. Here is the code i used

```
public void startTracking(View v)    {
    provider = new LocationGooglePlayServicesWithFallbackProvider(this);


    Log.i("Tag","Start Tracking");
    SmartLocation smartLocation = new SmartLocation.Builder(this)
            .logging(true)
            .build();

    smartLocation.location(provider)
            .config(LocationParams.BEST_EFFORT)
            .start(this);
    smartLocation.activity().start(this);
}

public void stopTracking(View v) {
    Log.i("Tag","Stop Tracking");
    SmartLocation.with(this).location().stop();
    SmartLocation.with(this).activity().stop();

}

@Override
public void onActivityUpdated(DetectedActivity detectedActivity)
{
    Log.i("Tag","ActivityUpdate : "+detectedActivity.toString());
}

@Override
public void onLocationUpdated(Location location)
{
    Log.i("Tag","LocationUpdate : "+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude());
}
```

This is the Logcat output I got

```
 01-27 14:09:01.791 3038-3038/com.angulusits.smartlocationtest I/Tag:
 Start Tracking 

 01-27 14:09:01.879 3038-3038/com.angulusits.smartlocationtest I/Tag:
 ActivityUpdate : DetectedActivity [type=STILL, confidence=100] 

 01-27 14:09:02.017 3038-3038/com.angulusits.smartlocationtest I/Tag:
 LocationUpdate : <some-value>,<some-value>
```

This is given as soon as i press startButton, Then no more values.

I checked the code on the Library for BEST_EFFORT value which is :

```
public static final LocationParams BEST_EFFORT = new Builder().setAccuracy(LocationAccuracy.MEDIUM).setDistance(150).setInterval(2500).build();
```

So I expected updates every *2500 millisecs* even if device is not moving.
I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I too facing the same issue. the onLocationUpdated is calling once when i initiated the start but after that no updates. thanks for any reply

Answer (score 18):

You need to say `continuous()` while creating the location listener.
Try this code snippet below,

```
private void startLocationListener() {

    long mLocTrackingInterval = 1000 * 5; // 5 sec
    float trackingDistance = 0;
    LocationAccuracy trackingAccuracy = LocationAccuracy.HIGH;

    LocationParams.Builder builder = new LocationParams.Builder()
            .setAccuracy(trackingAccuracy)
            .setDistance(trackingDistance)
            .setInterval(mLocTrackingInterval);

    SmartLocation.with(this)
            .location()
            .continuous()
            .config(builder.build())
            .start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {
                    processLocation(location);
                }
            });
}
```

Its late reply! Anyway this would help someone.

Comment: This answer seems to be no longer relevant as the method definition for continuous is
`public SmartLocation.LocationControl continuous() {
            this.oneFix = false;
            return this;
        }`

This has no impact unless the user explicitly calls oneFix().

Answer (score -3):

Its much better to use GoogleFuse Api.[Here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/) is the complete documentation of this Api.Its much better than using Github library for location tracking .

Comment: Care to explain why? The library seems to abstract Android Location Fused Provider and some other providers if needed.

Comment: @IvoPereira ..The smart location library can be changed to handle changes in location variation.. although for a newbie using abstracted library should not be recommended ... The smartv location library also has adidtional  features like activity recognition etc which is not needed and makes the apk large..I am not against using abstract library but when it comes to learning and using the source from where other libraries our created ..its much better to learn the source first and then use such libraries.Hope this helps